# Grails move data from application.properties

Tags: grails

on `application.propterty` of grails project, I got `mobile.version = 1.0.0_0`,

after that, I connect and render by `render(grailsApplication.metadata.'mobile.version')`.

Now I'd like to move `mobive.version` to `web-app/WEB-INF/meta_data.properties.`

How can I connect to `meta_data.properties` to render `mobile.version`

**I got answer for those who need it.**

```
Properties configProps = new Properties();
        def absolutePath = grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("WEB-INF").file.absolutePath
        def sep = System.getProperty('file.separator')
        URL u = new URL("file:${absolutePath}${sep}meta_data.properties");
        InputStream ip = u.openStream();
        configProps.load(ip);
        render (configProps.'mobile.version')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you found your answer, but I'd put the property in Config.groovy.  Then your code to access it is simply:

```
grailsApplication.config.mobile.version
```

Comment: Sure, it is the path to access file on configuration, my solution is how people access any particular paths on project. :)